# How do I output only country part of location field using the SimpleMap plugin?

Tags: plugin-simplemap

The docs of the [SimpleMap](https://github.com/ethercreative/simplemap) plugin mention it's possible to output only part of the full location, e.g. just the country by using

```
{{ myMapField.country_short }}
```

but in my project I get this error when I try doing so:

```
Internal Server Error

Craft\SimpleMap_MapModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "country".
```

Same result without the _short suffix.
The plugin is set up properly as I can correctly output full address, lat, lng, zoom values like so:

```
{{ myMapField.address }}
{{ myMapField.lat }}
{{ myMapField.lng }}
```

Just splitting up the full address results in the above error. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, posting answer for future reference:

It seems the official docs provide a wrong example for outputting the parts. Instead of using `{{ myMapField.country_short }}` as mentioned in the docs, you have to use `{{ myMapField.parts.country_short }}` (or without the _short suffix). This will correctly output just the country part of the full address.

Answer (score 1):

Never used the plugin, but from the docs:

> **parts**
>
> This contains the locations address, broken down into its constituent parts. All values are optional so you'll need to have checks on any you use to make sure they exist.
> A list of the available values can be found here.
> To access the short version of any part, append _short to the end of its name. E.g. {{ myMapField.country_short }}.

Sounds like the country info is optional and may not exist on the model, hence the note to check if it exists or not first.

i.e.

```
{% if myMapField.country_short is defined %}
    {{ myMapField.country_short }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it does not solve the error. For the record the values I use are actually `{{ entry.myMapField }} {{ entry.myMapField.address }} {{ entry.myMapField.lat }}` etc. (in a for loop). Any other ideas?

Comment: Jake please let me know if you got this figured out yet, I am running into the same.